# windowClosing not called in JFileChooser && System.exit not functioning properly?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser, system.exit

### Background

So I've been trying to improve my code style and write a bit more functionally. I write software daily not as a requirement for my job (web design), but to expedite my responsibilities and automate them and save time (this approach has proven invaluable and made me somewhat of a superstar).

### Issue

In one of my recent projects, I have tried to use a JFileChooser in the following way:

```
List<String> lines;
    do {
        lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            lines = jFC.showOpenDialog(new JFrame() {
                {
                    // originally setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
                    ? Files.readAllLines(jFC.getSelectedFile().toPath())
                    : null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error selecting File.");
        }
        System.out.println("Here we go");
    } while (lines == null || lines.isEmpty());
```

However neither my original implementation nor my revised one actually work, which I tested using print statements (The reimplemented version was never called.) I then tried to do the following:

```
JFrame test = new JFrame();
test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
lines = jFC.showOpenDialog(test) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
        ? Files.readAllLines(jFC.getSelectedFile().toPath())
        : null;
```

Which produced the same result. I've searched for duplicates but could not find something that reproduced my exact situation. Essentially, I want my program to completely terminate anytime a JFileChooser is canceled but I am reluctant to change my ternary statements as it does not fix my intended behavior but instead proposes a work around. My intuition tells me its a scope problem but for windowClosing not to be called raises a few questions for me.

### tl;dr

System.exit(0) on JFrame for JFileChooser not working, not going to change flow control so don't bother asking.

Comment: What do you think that the parameter you send to the `showOpenDialog` is for ? You don't need to create a `JFrame`, you can pass `null` to that method.

Comment: You might try `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);` instead of `System.exit(0)`, although basically are the same... just a thought

Comment: @assembler No need for all that. The program will exit if he doesn't create a new `JFrame`.

Comment: I believe I understand the problem. I was misinterpreting the functionality of the JFileChooser. I was under the impression that although it does return constants for the selected option, I didn't realize from the javadoc that it was actually not doing anything with  the functionality of the gui object passed to it and merely setting the look and feel (which seems like rather wasteful).

Comment: @Titus `showOpenDialog(null)` doesn't actually exit the program if that's what you're referring to although it still returned the cancel option.

Comment: What the parent argument does is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.String-) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#overview).

Comment: I think most of my issue came from the fact that I've been declaring my variables like this: `JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
   {
    setSize(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
    setUndecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);
   }
  };` so without thinking I just copy and pasted from a similar method and expected it to work. Thank you for clearing the air.

Comment: My point was that you don't need a `JFrame`. Your program doesn't exit because you're creating that `JFrame`. Even if you call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` it won't exit because you're never closing the `JFrame`.

Comment: I understand now, my point being that while I see now what it's doing unfortunately java doesn't support void types in their ternary statements so I'm still left with an if statement after, but imo that's really a language spec issue. It is rather unfortunate that you can't edit the functionality of a JFileChooser.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to accomplish.  Do you want to exit if the user cancels the dialog without choosing a file?  Why not just check for `JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION`?

Comment: I know my question is rather lengthy but “Essentially, I want my program to completely terminate anytime a JFileChooser is cancelled but I am reluctant to change my ternary statements because I do not want to change the flow of control” is in my mind the answer to that question.

Comment: I don’t understand the artificial “must use ternary operator” restraint, but you are using a null value to indicate two things:  failure and cancelation.  If you are also artificially restricting yourself from using `continue` and `break`, you may need to invent an `enum` to represent your three possible states (success, error, cancelation), and change your `while` condition to check your enum variable.